# Img not showing up in http server but does otherwise

Tags: html, image, http-status-code-404, src, web-inspector

Im grabbing image src from url and the image doesnt show on the page. If I go to the inspector and click on the img url it shows up on the new tab just fine.  Also if I right click the "img not there" img, and open image in new tab it also shows just fine.  It says in the network tab that there is a 404 but im just confused why it says that cause if I click the url for the src it shows up.  I learned a little about CORs and nothing ive tried for that has worked so far.  Made a free account for webhosting here thinking maybe something more real would work but same thing. https://funkocollector.x10.mx/ You can try searching for like Luke and see the other images dont load as well.

[inspector showing src is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYmIr.png)

[Network tab showing 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUxtO.png)

[Image showing up not on http](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ7V3.png)

[Image not showing on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kiiik.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; this is most likely a CORS block. Just to be sure, check for a CORS protocol error message in the Inspect screen.

The CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) protocol limits what you can link to from your http server for network security reasons. Your link may or may not be blocked depending on the type of file and the settings of the server you are linking to. You have 2 solutions, both relatively simple:

1. Quick fix: since you can open the image source, simply download the file to your computer and upload onto your server. Change the href to your own site.
2. Long-term solution: get an ssl on your server. If you’re registered with dns, get [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) for your server. You’ll then be accessible as https, and CORS won’t be a problem.

Comment: Dang alright I think Ill try and do that.  I dont see any CORs errors in the inspector but yea thats still my only guess.  Right now Im taking data from a json which uses a network request or something so I HAVE to be on a local server to even test so I guess I need to figure out how to get https on localhost. Hopefully that solves things. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I have been using the http-server command to test functionality of the program and learned you can use http-server -S -C (your certificate) to start https on the local server and I downloaded and used openssl to make a cert and key.  I can open the program in https now but it crosses out the https cause my computer says it doesnt trust the certificate.  Ive been looking everywhere for tutorials on how to get the Browser to trust it and havent figured it out.  So still havent confirmed whether https is the main issue.  If I figure out how to have my pc trust the self signed cert ill mark done.